# Cloud formation custom resource creation fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a custom resource which points to a lambda function and then invoke it to generate random Priority or my ELB Listener.

Code for Lambda function is as follows.

```cs
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]
namespace aws_listenser_rule_priority_generator {
    public class Function {
        public async Task<int> FunctionHandler(FunctionParams input, ILambdaContext context) {
            AmazonElasticLoadBalancingV2Client elbV2Client = new AmazonElasticLoadBalancingV2Client(RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
            var describeRulesResponse = await elbV2Client.DescribeRulesAsync(new DescribeRulesRequest  {
                ListenerArn = input.ListenerArn
            });
            var priority = 0;
            var random = new Random();
            do {
                priority = random.Next(1, 50000);
            }
            while(describeRulesResponse.Rules.Exists(r => r.Priority == priority.ToString()));
            
            return priority;
        }
    }

    public class FunctionParams {
        public string ListenerArn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have tested this lambda on AWS console with the following parameters and it returns successfully.

```json
{
  "ListenerArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:706137030892:listener/app/Cumulus/dfcf28e0393cbf77/cdfe928b0285d5f0"
}
```

But as soon as I try to use this with Cloud Formation. The Custom Resource is stuck at creation in progress.

```yaml
Resources:
  ListenerPriority:
    Type: Custom::Number
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:706137030892:function:GenerateListenerPriority"
      ListenerArn: "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:706137030892:listener/app/Cumulus/dfcf28e0393cbf77/cdfe928b0285d5f0"
```

Comment: CF creates lambda function for your custom resource. This lambda creates log group in cloudwatch, which you can check for errors

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha Thanks for the input. Tried the logs but strangely found none, which I think means the function is not called at all. Though I have found a solution after going through this [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudformation.html). We need to strictly adhere to a format for lambda function for custom resources. I will post it as answer if this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the previous approach was the data format. When we are working with the Custom Resources, Cloud Formation sends a request in a specified format and response is expected asynchronously at a specified response URL.

I had to make following updates to the code:

```cs
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]
namespace aws_listenser_rule_priority_generator
{
    public class Function
    {
        public async Task FunctionHandler(CustomResourceRequest<CustomResourceRequestProperties> crfRequest, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            var jsonResponse = string.Empty;
            
            if(crfRequest.RequestType.ToUpperInvariant() != "CREATE") {
                jsonResponse = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new CustomResourceResponse<object> {
                    Status = "SUCCESS",
                    Reason = string.Empty,
                    PhysicalResourceId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    StackId = crfRequest.StackId,
                    RequestId = crfRequest.RequestId,
                    LogicalResourceId = crfRequest.LogicalResourceId,
                    Data = new {
                        Dummy = "Dummy"
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                AmazonElasticLoadBalancingV2Client elbV2Client = new AmazonElasticLoadBalancingV2Client(RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
                var describeRulesResponse = await elbV2Client.DescribeRulesAsync(new DescribeRulesRequest  {
                    ListenerArn = crfRequest.ResourceProperties.ListenerArn
                });
                var priority = 0;
                var random = new Random();
                do {
                    priority = random.Next(1, 50000);
                }
                while(describeRulesResponse.Rules.Exists(r => r.Priority == priority.ToString()));

                jsonResponse = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new CustomResourceResponse<object> {
                    Status = "SUCCESS",
                    Reason = string.Empty,
                    PhysicalResourceId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    StackId = crfRequest.StackId,
                    RequestId = crfRequest.RequestId,
                    LogicalResourceId = crfRequest.LogicalResourceId,
                    Data = new {
                        Priority = priority
                    }
                });
            }
            var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonResponse);
            
            var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(crfRequest.ResponseURL) as HttpWebRequest;
            webRequest.Method = "PUT";
            webRequest.ContentType = string.Empty;
            webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            
            using(Stream datastream = webRequest.GetRequestStream()) {
                await datastream.WriteAsync(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }

            await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
        }
    }
    public class CustomResourceRequest<T> where T : ICustomResourceRequestProperties {
        public string RequestType { get; set; }
        public string ResponseURL { get; set; }
        public string StackId { get; set; }
        public string RequestId { get; set; }
        public string ResourceType { get; set; }
        public string LogicalResourceId{ get; set; }
        public string PhysicalResourceId { get; set; }
        public T ResourceProperties { get; set; }
        public T OldResourceProperties { get; set; }
    }
    public class CustomResourceResponse<T> {
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Reason { get; set; }
        public string PhysicalResourceId { get; set; }
        public string StackId { get; set; }
        public string RequestId { get; set; }
        public string LogicalResourceId { get; set; }
        public bool NoEcho { get; set; }
        public T Data { get; set; }
    }
    public interface ICustomResourceRequestProperties {
        public string ServiceToken { get; set; }
    }
    public class CustomResourceRequestProperties : ICustomResourceRequestProperties
    {
        string ICustomResourceRequestProperties.ServiceToken { get; set; }
        public string ListenerArn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The above code expects everything to work without any issues and there are no try catch blocks. Best practice would be to have try catch blocks and send a failure response.

Following URLs can be referred for more details:

- [Custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html)
- [Custom resource request objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/crpg-ref-requests.html)
- [Custom resource response objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/crpg-ref-responses.html)
- [Using AWS Lambda with AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudformation.html)